# get matrix of vectors from a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a vector `x = [1,3,5,6,7]` and I want to produce a matrix `y` in which rows y(k) = x(k:k+2). So the resulting matrix in this case would be

```
1 3 5
3 5 6
5 6 7
```

How can I achieve this **without** using a loop? Is there a clever way of doing it with indexing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the top non-zero square of a [Hankel matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix). Just use [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html):

```
>> X = hankel(x)
X =
     1     3     5     6     7
     3     5     6     7     0
     5     6     7     0     0
     6     7     0     0     0
     7     0     0     0     0
>> X = X(1:3,1:3)
X =
     1     3     5
     3     5     6
     5     6     7
```

Generalized, `hankel` output specified exactly:

```
w = floor(numel(x)/2);
X = hankel(x(1:end-w),x(w+1:end))
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly contrived way using `meshgrid`:

```
k = (length(x) + 1) / 2;
[a b] = meshgrid(1:k, 0:k-1);
y = x(a+b);
```

Or the compact equivalent using `bsxfun`

```
y = x(bsxfun(@plus, (1:k)', 0:k-1));
```

Or a *really* silly one-liner:

```
y = x(interp2([1 3], [1;3], [1 3; 3 5], 1:3, (1:3)'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the following way without direct loop:

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) x(k:k+2), 1:numel(x) - 2, 'UniformOutput', false)')

ans =

     1     3     5
     3     5     6
     5     6     7
```

Though, `arrayfun` actually loops over elements `1:numel(x) - 2`. So its a bit of cheating, i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Using convolutions:

```
n = numel(x)-2; %// x is a row vector with arbitrary length
result = conv2(x,rot90(eye(n)));
result = result(:,n:end-n+1);
```