# In theano, making the matrix of slices from a vector

Tags: python, theano

I want to do the same thing in [get matrix of vectors from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159774/get-matrix-of-vectors-from-a-vector) in theano.

Maybe, it can be worked with scan().
But i dont know how scan() can be applied in this problem.

Following is the code for context.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

self.x = T.vector('x')
self.i = T.imatrix('i') 
#indices tuple list. ex)[[0,3],[1,4]] means two slices (from 0 to 3 and from 1 to 4)

self.slices_list = ? #slices from the vector self.x
```

Comment: In numpy this can be done using stride tricks (`from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided`) by creating the appropriate view on the 1D array. AFAIK in theano this possibility does not exist. So you have either scan or fixed size for loop using `set_subtensor` as options. A very contrived way of doing this would be using fourier transform.

Answer (score 0):

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

self.x = T.vector('x')
self.i = T.imatrix('i') 
#indices tuple list. ex)[[0,3],[1,4]] means two slices (from 0 to 3 and from 1 to 4)

results, updates = theano.scan(lambda v:self.x[v[0]:v[1]], sequences=self.i)
make_slices = theano.function(inputs=[self.x,self.i], outputs=[results])    

self.slices_list = make_slices(x,i)
#'x' and 'i' are theano shared variables
```